# No me pide para poder ingresar datos dentro del arreglo

Tags: c++, array

Cuando lo realizo sin funciones, funciona correctamente.
Cuando le incorporo las funciones, me pide el tamaño del array unidimensional, pero no me pide que llene el vector[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void TamanioVector(int Cantidad);
void LlenarVector(int Cantidad, int Array[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int Array[99];
    int Cantidad=0, Suma=0;
    TamanioVector(Cantidad);
    LlenarVector(Cantidad,Array);
}
void TamanioVector(int Cantidad){
    cout<<"\n Ingrese Tamano del Vector: ";
    cin>>Cantidad;
}
void LlenarVector(int Cantidad, int Array[]){
    int Suma=0;
    for(int i=0;i<Cantidad;i++){
        cout<<"\n Array["<<i<<"]: ";
        cin>>Array[i];
        Suma+=Array[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voy a ocupar la misma lógica de lo que tú tienes para sumar 2 números

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void Sumar(int suma,int a, int b);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int suma=0;
    Sumar(suma,1,2);
    cout<<"\n Suma = "<<suma; // Suma = 0
}
void Sumar(int suma, int a, int b){
    suma = a+b;
}
```

La suma da cero, porque?? porque el argumento es pasado por valor. Debes investigar a fondo sobre "pasar por referencia o por valor". Pero te puedo adelantar, que cuando pasas "por valor" el argumento de una función no sufre cambios fuera de la función (es como si hubieras pasado una copia no el original) y al contrario, cuando lo hace por referencia si lo hace.

Otra alternativa, que es la mejor y más fácil, es retornar algo

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int Sumar(int a, int b);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int suma = Sumar(1,2);
    cout<<"\n Suma = "<<suma; // Suma = 3
}
int Sumar( int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}
```

Como quedaría tu código

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int TamanioVector();
void LlenarVector(int Array[], int Cantidad);
int SumarArray(int Array[], int Cantidad);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    int Cantidad = TamanioVector();
    
    int Array[Cantidad];
    LlenarVector(Array,Cantidad);
    
    int suma =SumarArray(Array, Cantidad);
    cout<<"\n Suma = "<<suma;
}

int TamanioVector(){
    int Cantidad=0;
    cout<<"\n Ingrese Tamano del Vector: ";
    cin>>Cantidad;
    return Cantidad;
}

void LlenarVector(int Array[], int Cantidad){
    for(int i=0;i<Cantidad;i++){
        cout<<"\n Array["<<i<<"]: ";
        cin>>Array[i];
    }
}

int SumarArray(int Array[], int Cantidad){
    int Suma=0;
    for(int i=0;i<Cantidad;i++){
        Suma+=Array[i];
    }
    return Suma;
}
```

Nota: si te fijas en la función LlenarVector si obedece a la lógica que tú tienes en tu pregunta, esto es porque al pasar el argumento como int array[] lo estas pasando por referencia.